# jQuery scale pulsate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to instruct my user on how to interact with a part of a website with a drawn arrow and handwritten instructions. I also want it to scale up and down repeatedly in a pulsate effect with jQuery. I know there is a pulsate plugin for jQuery, but I don't know how to mix that with scale. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: In what way do you want 'it' (whatever 'it' is) to interact with 'scale'? The scale of what? Also, what have you tried so far, and what's your mark-up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, the jQuery pulsate is for opacity only.  Instead of that, I wrote a quick "pulse" function.  Just animates smaller, then larger and starts again.  You need to call `pulse` in onload.

```
function pulse() {
 $('#arrow').animate({
    height: '200px'
  }, 400, function() {
    // First animate complete
    $('#arrow').animate({
      height: '150px'
      }, 400, function() {
        // Second animate complete
        pulse();
    });
  });
}
```

See demo here:

http://jsbin.com/ejeni4/2/

http://jsbin.com/ejeni4/2/edit

There may be a better way, and of course you probably need to clean up the css to make it point where you want, etc.